# R package for spatial lag/error model for binary dependent variable as a rare event

Tags: r, binary, regression, spatial

I intend to model the relationship between a binary dependent variables and some other variables. Since the data is spatial, it is desirable to employ a spatial lag or error model. Also the binary dependent variable represents a rare event (small number of cases with value of 1). Is there any R package (or other software package) that can meet the above modelling requirements?

Comment: This may be better asked in the stats.stackoverflow.com site. However, the best I have used for analysis can be found here. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logistf/logistf.pdf). If you are interested in correlation structures for your dataset, I can point you to here.
 (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/gls.html). As for using both, I am not sure if there exists a package that can do that.

Comment: Thanks Jacobs. Will look into both. Cheers.